# Store multiple custom field as post meta per post(css, js, html, 2 link)

Tags: php, custom-field, post-meta, table

I want to make **Wordpress** faster. So, instead of using multiple templates, I want to put sidebar(`html`), small css file(syntax highlighter, `prism.css` css content as inline directly to post, to reduce http request), small js file(syntax highlighter, `prism.js` js content as inline directly to post inside `<script>` `</script>` to reduce http req) and two links(**newer** and **older**).

I want to store them in database, and when website get request for specific post, the query will look for `wp_content` and add five meta fields stored and join them together.

1. I am going blank, how to do all these- the `js` and `css` files are short and will remain short numbered, 60+60 for both js and css. I want to store the css and js content inside mysql postmeta table, and want to add from Wordpress Editor page as **Dropdown**.
2. Also two other custom field to put links on **newer** and **older** post link to the button.
3. And sidebar content as `html` document

How to do these without plugin, and want to make my **Wordpress** Robust and faster, how to achieve this with .

By putting - `add action()` inside function.php could achieve multiple custom field requirement, but how to store the css and js content inside **postmeta** field and make the drop-down to achieve, adding which particular `Js` and `css`, sidebar(`html`) values?

Any help would be appreciated, I want detailed answer, if any method which breaks or slows Wordpress is not expected at all, better to implement anything complicated but not breaking Wordpress.

Comment: Would you consider 'performance tuning' your existing installation via MySQL Server Global Variable changes?  If you would, view profile, Network profile.